# Is rsync the best tool for transfering partially downloaded content on the fly?

Tags: linux, bash, rsync, bittorrent

I want to sync my home NAS with my VPS to have my legal torrents available on my NAS as soon as they are fully transferred. What I used to do is transfer them when they are fully downloaded on my VPS but that makes me lose a lot of time.

Here is a drawing of what I think could be one of the solution (please don't hesitate to criticize it):

[image: Diagram of proposed solution]

For that purpose, do you think a rsync script running on the NAS is the most adequate way to do it (rsync the .part every minute then if the file is no more in the "not yet completed" folder but in the "completed" folder rename the .part to completed extension then rsync again and then move it to the NAS "finished" folder)?

Comment: Why don't you download the files directly to the NAS by using a network share?

Comment: Easy to try, don't ask, experiment :)  However, if you have a little bit of seed time once you have got everything, you'll have a full copy from the "downloading" folder and won't have to to try to do the finishing incremental copy on the "downloaded" one.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `rsync`.

Since torrented files are built from independently transferred blocks, and that initially you might have a beginning and an end but no middle, I would suggest you consider either the `--sparse` flag (skip over the writing of blocks containing only zeros) or the `--inplace` flag (update the file *in situ* rather than repeatedly writing a temporary file). Of the two I think I'd recommend `--inplace`:

```
rsync --archive --inplace source_host:/path/to/source/dir/ /path/to/local/destination/
```